# Why are StackOverflow notifications not captured by Firebug?

Tags: notifications, firebug

I am browsing the StackOverflow site using Firefox. I have multiple windows open on multiple tabs from the same site. When there is a notification, I see the notification number (in red color) on all the open windows, but I do not see any trace of it in Firebug in form of request. I was looking at the [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel).

What technology does StackOverflow use for notifications and why is that not captured by Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like stackoverflow is using [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for these notifications, which are currently not supported by Firebug. There's a [request for adding support for them](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6330), though.

A WebSocket allows bidirectional communication between client and server. That means the server can send messages to the client without a request from the client-side.